# My C# code doesn't read special characters from file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

as the title suggest, I have a problem with my c# code not reading files correctly, because when I try to read characters from file such as: č, ć, š, đ, ž, etc., I get �. I need my program to be able to read all characters even from other languages. I also tried using Encoding parameter with UTF-8 and Default but that also didn't work. Below is an example of code.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: How is your file encoded?

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't really know, from what I can see on windows notepad when I open the file it says ANSI on the bottom so I guess that? I am reading the lines from an .srt subtitle file.

Comment: Where are you trying to print your strings?

Comment: Your file could not UTF8 then, it could be one of specific, regional code pages. Instead of Encoding.UTF8 try Encoding.GetEncoding with one of [supported code pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0) (I personally bet on 852 or 1250).

Comment: @IvanLoGreco first I tried using only a foreach loop and then print it to the console but that also didn't work. Then I tried looking at the strings in the VS2022 debugger view of the array and there it also showed the ? symbol. And the last thing I tried is to just make a new file and paste the content there and the story is the same.

Comment: @WiktorZychla is maybe there one that suits all languages?

Comment: There isn't, ANSI code pages are specific to your Windows locale. Why don't you just check 1250 and 852? Or, consult the linked list to find the one that matches your locale.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File ReadAllLines turns foreign language into gibberish (�)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042439/file-readalllines-turns-foreign-language-into-gibberish)

Comment: @WiktorZychla I tried Like that "Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(852);" but it threw an error. System.NotSupported exception

Comment: @ChristophLütjen unfortunately no, I got this error "System.ArgumentException: ''Windows-1255' is not a supported encoding name."

Comment: This is not a copy and paste answer. You have a text file that is encoded with a non UTF-8 encoding and we cannot tell you about the exact value for this because we don't have the text file. The answer is: You have to specify the encoding used in your file when reading it. There are online tools available that can help you or you simply try some. If you get "NotSupported", you can list the supported enconding like so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=net-6.0

Comment: @AGlasencnik Please [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider.getencoding?view=net-6.0) before just asking for an encoding (hint: call `CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1250)`)

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thank you so much, this worked! Now that this works I just need to figure out which encoding I need for which language, as my program must read from this kind of characters to example arabian, chinese etc etc

Comment: Great, will create an answer of that.

Comment: The UTF8 was designed to solve these issues and if you have any control of how source files are created, strongly recommend UTF8. This is because there's no easy way to *guess* code pages of abritrary files.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Then I will maybe look into how to first convert the file to UTF8. As this files will most probably be downloaded from the internet by the client. And as I said, they could be in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

> č, ć, š, đ, ž

suggests here that this could be one of ANSI code pages of Eastern Europe. A recommendation is then to try

```
CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1250)
```

as the encoding.

Sadly, there's no easy way to *guess* a code page of a 8-bit file. To overcome such issues, UTF-8 (and other unicode encodings) were designed. Thus, if there's a control on how source files are created, please strongly recommend to have UTF8 (or Unicode but there's no need) files.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
stringbuilder sb = new stringbuilder();

using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName,
                                       Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                                           outFileName, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately this didn't work.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: There was no error, it just did the same thing as I think Encoding.Default did. On some characters was a character like special "è" which is now instead of "?".